# Interesting combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

As a child I had a deck of cards which consisted of maybe 50 cards. On each card there were 6 objects. Players had to pick 2 cards from the deck, and the player who first spotted the difference between the 2 cards won.  The interesting thing was, that for evry 2 cards it was true that they only differed in 1 object.

Can someone explain how to construct such cards?

Comment: As ${9 \choose 6} =84$, you could have a deck of $84$ cards, each with six symbols out of nine.   Any pair would share at least three, but could share up to five.  It would be neat to see if you could throw away some $30$ of them and have each pair differ in two or three, making an error correcting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my comments that Barry Cipra's solution is the only way to construct the deck with only one object different, I'm posting a short proof of that fact.

Consider a deck of $50$ cards that has the property that every card differs in only one object from any other card and is not built where every card has $5$ objects the same and differs in only one spot (so not Barry's deck). Pick two cards at random and call the objects on them $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and $A,B,C,D,E,G$. Using only the so far named objects ($A,B,C,D,E,F,G$), it can be shown that there are only $7$ cards possible using these objects. Because the deck contains more than $7$ cards, there is a card that uses a new object, call it $H$. Pick any $5$ of the already used symbols and add $H$ to the card. This new card (say it is $A,B,C,D,E,H$ for easy reference) must differ in $2$ spots from $5$ of the $7$ already constructed cards. This is a contradiction to the assumptions. So either the deck is really built like Barry has suggested or the deck can not force every pair of cards to be different in only one symbol.

Comment: You are taking 6-subsets out of a total of 7 objects, i.e., $\binom{7}{6} = \binom{7}{1} = 7$ for the 7 possible cards.

Comment: Your contradiction assumes that the deck includes more than just the first two cards formed using objects $(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)$.  What if it doesn't?

Comment: A 2 card deck doesn't fit the OP description. So technically, I'm contradicting either (1) it keeps one symbol different on every pair, (2) it is constructed different from your suggestion, or (3) the deck has more than 7 cards.

Comment: @JohnHabert, you misunderstood my comment, which is admittedly a picky one.  What I meant is, having labeled the first two cards with the $7$ letters $(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)$, your proof assumes there is at least one more card using $6$ of those $7$ letters.

Comment: @BarryCipra I understand now. Since every card can differ in only one spot, every card has to use $5$ of those symbols. From there, you can still arrive at a contradiction since any card using $5$ of those symbols plus a new one and doesn't include $A$ will differ in two places from one of the first two cards. More cases than I originally thought but still breaks.

Answer (score 1):

One trivial way to construct such cards is to use a total of $55$ objects.  Let's label the objects $A,B,C,D,E,1,2,\ldots,50$.  Each card shows a set $\{A,B,C,D,E,k\}$ with $1\le k\le 50$.  But this is almost certainly not what the OP wants!

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution too, but as far as I remeber in my deck there weren't 55 objects.

Comment: @user137425 There is no other way to create a deck where each card differs only in one object. A deleted answer showed a way to create a deck where no more than 2 objects were different.

Comment: @JohnHabert, it's not obvious to me that there is no other way to create a deck where each card differs only in one object.  Could you post a proof?

Comment: Simple to prove. Without loss of generality, start with two cards ${A,B,C,D,E,1}$ and ${A,B,C,D,E,2}$. Now say you want to add a third card. It necessarily has to be of the form ${A,B,C,D,E,k}$ where $k\ne 1, 2$, otherwise it would differ from either the first or the second card in two or more places. Same argument for the remaining $47$ cards.

Comment: @user75267, the third card could be $A,B,C,D,1,2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Posted a proof as an answer. A few small details left out that I can add if needed.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I interpreted the question incorrectly, and thought that the order of the objects mattered as well.